# PHPMyadmin Error: #2002 - No such file or directory<br />The server is not responding

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, virtual-machine, lamp, ubuntu-16.04

I have phpMyAdmin installed on Ubuntu 16.04 Lamp Server on an Oracle VM. When I try to enter phpMyAdmin via *http://localhost/phpmyadmin*, I receive the following error:

> Error: #2002 - No such file or directory
> The server is not responding

After reading previous threads, I have tried to unsuccessfully reinstall mysql-server to no avail. The MySQL error log in */var/log/*... contains the following:

```
2017-01-22T16:18:06.214161Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 5000)
2017-01-22T16:18:06.214326Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 (requested 2000)
2017-01-22T16:18:06.536519Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2017-01-22T16:18:06.543467Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) starting as process 3647 ...
2017-01-22T16:18:06.571026Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2017-01-22T16:18:06.571095Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2017-01-22T16:18:06.571106Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2017-01-22T16:18:06.571120Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2017-01-22T16:18:06.571130Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2017-01-22T16:18:06.571139Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2017-01-22T16:18:06.571731Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2017-01-22T16:18:06.571975Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2017-01-22T16:18:06.577202Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2017-01-22T16:18:06.625715Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-01-22T16:18:06.631873Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2017-01-22T16:18:06.647876Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2017-01-22T16:18:06.736500Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2017-01-22T16:18:06.736633Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file \'./ibtmp1\' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2017-01-22T16:18:07.143892Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File \'./ibtmp1\' size is now 12 MB.
2017-01-22T16:18:07.145163Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2017-01-22T16:18:07.145188Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2017-01-22T16:18:07.150769Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2017-01-22T16:18:07.201406Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.17 started; log sequence number 16765716
2017-01-22T16:18:07.207484Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2017-01-22T16:18:07.208190Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 170122 17:18:07
2017-01-22T16:18:07.208412Z 0 [Note] Plugin \'FEDERATED\' is disabled.
2017-01-22T16:18:07.229256Z 0 [Warning] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key
2017-01-22T16:18:07.229286Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): \'127.0.0.1\'; port: 3306
2017-01-22T16:18:07.229302Z 0 [Note]   - \'127.0.0.1\' resolves to \'127.0.0.1\';
2017-01-22T16:18:07.229351Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: \'127.0.0.1\'.
2017-01-22T16:18:07.230207Z 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can\'t open and lock privilege tables: Incorrect file format \'user\'
2017-01-22T16:18:07.230287Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

');

I have tried to apply various solutions including this - [MySQL Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Incorrect file format 'user'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28521530/mysql-fatal-error-cant-open-and-lock-privilege-tables-incorrect-file-format)

Unfortunately, I am not able to access Mysql and therefore unable to follow the solution. $ sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables does not allow me to access it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Incorrect file format 'user'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28521530/mysql-fatal-error-cant-open-and-lock-privilege-tables-incorrect-file-format)

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not able to access Mysql and therefore unable to follow the solution. $ sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables does not allow me to access it.

Comment: According to your log excerpt MySQL is aborting because it can't access the `user` table. The commands to run in terminal at the possible duplicate question tell MySQL not to use these tables. If there is something else preventing it from running you will need to provide further details as to what that is.

Comment: I am a complete novice. Is there another way to diagnose the issue?

Comment: Your MySQL error log should show any further errors when you follow the instructions in the linked post. Alternatively, if you don't need the data you can completely remove MySQL with `sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-common* mysql-client* mysql-server*` and `sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql` then do a clean install.