# XAMPP Mysql not starting

Tags: mysql, xampp

I get this error when trying to start up Mysql on Xampp. Apache is starting just fine. This error happened out of nowhere.

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysqld --console
2023-04-12 23:09:57 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.4.17-MariaDB) starting as process 19816 ...
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2023-04-12 23:09:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2023-04-12 23:09:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2023-04-12 23:09:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2023-04-12 23:09:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2023-04-12 23:09:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2023-04-12 23:09:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2023-04-12 23:09:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2023-04-12 23:09:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Resizing redo log from 2*5242880 to 2*50331648 bytes; LSN=4093048
2023-04-12 23:09:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting to delete and rewrite log files.
2023-04-12 23:09:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file .\ib_logfile101 size to 50331648 bytes
2023-04-12 23:09:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file .\ib_logfile1 size to 50331648 bytes
2023-04-12 23:09:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Renaming log file .\ib_logfile101 to .\ib_logfile0
2023-04-12 23:09:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=4093048
2023-04-12 23:09:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2023-04-12 23:09:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2023-04-12 23:09:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file '.\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2023-04-12 23:09:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: File '.\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2023-04-12 23:09:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2023-04-12 23:09:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.17 started; log sequence number 4093048; transaction id 4613
2023-04-12 23:09:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from c:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2023-04-12 23:09:58 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2023-04-12 23:09:58 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2023-04-12 23:09:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 230412 23:09:58
2023-04-12 23:09:58 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Incorrect file format 'global_priv'
2023-04-12 23:09:58 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Incorrect file format 'user'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28521530/mysql-fatal-error-cant-open-and-lock-privilege-tables-incorrect-file-format)

Comment: Hello, no it doesn't. I have a windows computer so I cannot run the sudo command